# What do I put on my developers box in regard to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So we are venturing out into the world of SharePoint and it seems that I have to install SharePoint Server directly on each developer's box. Is this correct? I have SharePoint up and running on a separate sever so it seems redundant to have to install it on each box. Not to mention installing SharePoint on Windows 7 is a pain in the ars. I'm just trying to clarify how to correctly set the environment up. I've been using this link as a guide so far: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to install sharepoint on every box, just VS and the SDK. You should have a separate dev instance for them to connect to, but that should be a real server not a win7 desktop.

So you should have

1 Server with sharepoint 2010

N Dev workstations that have VS2010 and the SDK installed.

Comment: Does the SDK provide you with local or remote debugging capabilities or something? I have never developed for Sharepoint so I'm just curious, as my instinctive answer is yes a local instance will make it a lot easier to develop and debug against? Dev and test server environments would still be needed to provide infrastructure, AD, isolation for QA and so fourth of course... but for the local development process?

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was hoping to hear. Any chance you have an online resource you could point me too in regards to "connecting" VS and the dev sharepoint server?

Comment: @Oskar: I'm not sure, the last time I did sharepoint work was 2 or 3 years ago, but back then i could do remote debug pretty easily and without anything special (then again i have enterprise admin creds ... soo YMMV) I've since ditch sharepoint but still setup devs every now and again.

Comment: @Jisaak: Sorry see above havn't done anything active in a while besides installs. But if the interface hasn't changed too much you should just be able to go to file -> connect to sharepoint in VS

Comment: Ok. I'll see what I can find. The reason I thought I might have to have sharepoint server installed on each box is because when I go to Tools -> Add Sharepoint Connection an alert comes up saying "A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects." But anyways, thanks for clarifying the setup for me!

Comment: I found out that Visual Studio REQUIRES you to have Sharepoint Server installed on EACH developers local box.

Comment: @Jisaak: uhg sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

We've used Microsfoft VPC and installed Server 2008 and Sharepoint on that.  Then do dev either on your host PC or the VPC and deploy to the Sharepoint instance on your VPC to test your changes.  This way developers are stepping all over each other in a Development environment.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2008 cannot be installed on Microsoft VPC due to the fact that it needs Windows Server 2008 64-bit. Microsoft VPC cannot run a 64-bit Operating System, you'll need a different Virtualization Platform.

This can be confusing due to the fact that you can run a 64-bit version of Microsoft VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is couple practical tips for setting up SharePoint 2010 development environment:

[SharePoint 2010 Team Development Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vesku/sharepoint-2010-team-development-environment) by Vesa Juvonen

[SharePoint 2010 Development Environment Practical Tips](https://web.archive.org/web/20170907142205/http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-11-SharePoint_2010_Development_Environment_-and-ndash;_Practical_Tips.aspx) by Sahil Malik